# What is the difference between TEXMFHOME and TEXINPUTS?

Tags: packages, installing, texmf

A question was asked:
[Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/7142)
basically says the following:

1. Create a local texmf tree,
   say at the folder `~/localtexmf`,
2. Add the folder to the search path, e.g. on a Mac running TeXLive

   ```
   tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME "~/Library/texmf:~/localtexmf"
   ```

Another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1142/7142) suggests to edit the `.bashrc` file and to add a line

```
TEXINPUTS="~/localtexmf:"
```

**Question:** What is the difference between `TEXMFHOME` and `TEXINPUTS`?
Are the two solutions basically the same?